# caml Query Returning Last Item in List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a CamlQuery which I set as follows:

```
function getPartID(partName) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/HepatoChemKitCustomizationForms/');
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PartsTable');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Part_x0020_Name" /><Value Type="Text">' + partName + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onPartQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onPartQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    partID = (oListItem.get_item('Part_x0020_ID'));
}
```

}

'Part Name' is an existing field in the table on which I'm running the query, it is a text field, and the variable partName contains a string which is included in this field in the table.

However, the query returns the last item in the table instead of this one (one of the first items, not that it matters).

I've tried deleting the last item to see if there was something specific about that one but it happened again with the new last item.

I'm new to caml so I don't know what it going wrong with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I think I found the problem. When I ran alert (partName + " " + oListItem.get_item('Part_x0020_Name')); it shows this:

[image]

I don't know why the string is being built with a carriage return though. I use the following code to build the string:

```
(catalystArray[i] + "/" + baseArray[j]);
```

If the object from catalystArray does have a carriage return tacked onto it, how would I remove it?

UPDATE:

Solved it. Dumb mistake, but it took me all day to find.

```
catalystArray[i].replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
baseArray[i].replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
(catalystArray[i] + "/" + baseArray[j]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the View XML of a CAML Query object, you should include the outer `<View>` and `<Query>` elements in your XML.

If the XML is not in a format recognized by SharePoint, it'll perform a default query that will (usually) return all items. That is likely what is happening in your case, with the code enumerating through all the items in the results. As a consequence, only the last item's values are stored to the variables you expected.

Comment: When I add that in it returns an empty string.

Comment: The code snippet you provided doesn't look like it returns anything... Could you edit your question to include your full code?

Comment: The idea is to have the query return the record which has Part Name that matches the partName variable. Would this query not do that?

Comment: This CAML query (when passed to `getItems()` on a list object) will retrieve any items where the field with an internal name of `Part_x0020_Name` is exactly equal to the text in the `partName` variable. But we'd need to see the rest of your code to know if you're using the CAML Query object correctly to query the list or if there might be some other subtle errors.